# Asynchronous RPC in c++ (using visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rpc, msdn

I am trying to program an Asynchronous RPC in c++ (using visual studio). As per the documentation provided by the MSDN ([Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373550(v=vs.85).aspx)), I need to modify the ".ACF" file. But I am not able to find that file. I need suggestions on how to find that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't exist, create it.

Note that this is truly ancient technology.